# Soft delete on a intermediate table for many-to-many relationship

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

How do I set soft delete on an intermediate table which is connecting two different types of entities? I've added  deleted_at column, but the docs say that I need to put this into the model:

```
protected $softDelete = true;
```

Of course, I don't have a model for an intermediate table. 
Any idea?

Comment: Another alternative is to try this https://github.com/mlezcano1985/laravel-pivot-soft-deletes

Answer (score 82, accepted):

You can put a constraint on the Eager Load:

```php
public function groups()
    {

        return $this
        ->belongsToMany('Group')
        ->whereNull('group_user.deleted_at') // Table `group_user` has column `deleted_at`
        ->withTimestamps(); // Table `group_user` has columns: `created_at`, `updated_at`

    }
```

Instead of HARD deleting the relationship using:

```php
User::find(1)->groups()->detach();
```

You should use something like this to SOFT delete instead:

```php
DB::table('group_user')
    ->where('user_id', $user_id)
    ->where('group_id', $group_id)
    ->update(array('deleted_at' => DB::raw('NOW()')));
```

Comment: Does the belongsToMany take deleted_at in account?

Comment: Yes. That's what the `whereNull('group_user.deleted_at')` is for.

Comment: @RonaldHulshof I have tried this way, how to soft delete using `User::find(1)->groups()->detach();`

Comment: I've been looking for this answer. Nailed it.

Comment: You can change the update to this ```->update(['deleted_at' => Carbon\Carbon::now()]);``` if you want to keep the query testable against a Sqlite database.

Comment: This is great and answered and my question. However, there would be an issue when trying to find soft deleted pivots on the relation. For example, I have a compound index of user_id and group_id. If the pivot is soft deleted I cannot check to see if the relation currently exists to then set the deleted_at field back to null. Otherwise the pivot record creation will fail due to already being indexed.

Comment: Agreeing with @BradBird, still need an equivalent to `Model::withTrashed()` and `Model::onlyTrashed()`.

Answer (score 18):

You could also use Laravel's Eloquent `BelongsToMany` method `updateExistingPivot`.

```
$model->relation->updateExistingPivot($relatedId, ['deleted_at' => Carbon\Carbon::now()]);
```

So to use @RonaldHulshof examples you have a User model with a groups relationship which is a `belongsToMany` relationship.

```
public function groups() {
    return $this->belongsToMany(Group::class)->whereNull('groups_users.deleted_at')->withTimestamps();
}
```

Then in order to soft delete the pivot table entry you would do the following.

```
$user->groups()->updateExistingPivot($groupId, ['deleted_at' => Carbon\Carbon::now()]);
```

Comment: You could use `wherePivot('deleted_at', null)` instead of using `whereNull('groups_users.deleted_at')`. This works the same.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I understand it; an intermediate table is simply a length of string attaching one tables record to a record in another table and as such it does not require a soft delete method.

To explain, imagine you have a Users table and a Groups table, each user can have more than one Group and each Group can belong to more than one User. Your pivot table may be `User_Group` or something like that and it simply contains two columns `user_id` and `group_id`.

Your `User` table and `Group` table should have a `deleted_at` column for soft deletes, so when you "delete" say a Group, that group association will not appear in `$User->Groups()` while the pivot table row has remained unaffected. If you then restore that deleted Group, it will once again appear in `$User->Groups()`.

The pivot table row should only be affected if that group record is hard deleted, in which case the pivot rows should also be hard deleted.

Now I have explained why I do not believe you need to add soft delete to a pivot table; is there still a reason why you need this behavior?

Comment: What I need is to know that user was related to a group, so that's why I need soft delete - this connection remains in the db, although it's not active. Makes sense?

Comment: Ah yes, in which case you can add an additional row on your pivot table such as `deleted_at` and then follow R. Hulshof's answer :)

Comment: Rare exception to this rule: if you wish to keep historical tracking of when relationships where added and removed, then having a soft delete option is useful.