# How to turn off pivot deletion when soft deleting in the main table?

Tags: php, many-to-many, laravel, eloquent, soft-delete

I have a `Users` and a `Groups` table in Laravel's Eloquent ORM. There can be multiple users in a group and a user can be in multiple groups, so I use a pivot table to realize the many-to-many relationship. In real, the relationship isn't many-to-many because every user can be in only one group, but the system was designed this way. I soft delete the rows in the `Users` table so if needed I can restore users later.

The problem is that when I delete a user, the system automatically delete the entry in the pivot table too. This is always one entry. I didn't set it to behave like this, only added the  `protected $softDelete = true;` line to the `Users` model, so I don't understand why the system automatically delete the pivot entries.

I don't want to soft delete the pivot entries, I want to soft delete only and exclusively the users, and the system shouldn't touch anything else.
I could create my own delete function that set the `deleted_at` variable to the actual time but this way I couldn't simply turn of the soft delete by changing the `true` to `false` if I need this.

Why does the system automatically delete the pivot entries, and how can I turn off this behavior?

Comment: Another answer is suggesting to add a constraint in your many-to-many relationship to filter, not exactly what you expected, also not sure if it works. http://stackoverflow.com/a/18144975/439427

Comment: I meant to filter trashed relationships.

Comment: In my experience, when soft deleting a row it wont delete the pivot entries, can you give us an example of your Model and code?

Answer (score 1):

Check your database if you are using foreign keys you may have it set to ON UPDATE, ON DELETE "CASCADE". You need to set it up to "NO ACTION"

```
CONSTRAINT `fk_USER_Address_1` FOREIGN KEY (`userId`) REFERENCES `USER` (`userId`) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE,
```

to

```
CONSTRAINT `fk_USER_Address_1` FOREIGN KEY (`userId`) REFERENCES `USER` (`userId`) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE NO ACTION,
```