# How to use soft delete to delete many to many relationship models eloquent laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, soft-delete

I am going to delete a role in my table. The structure of `roles`,`permissions` and `permissions_roles` are:

```
-- auto-generated definition
create table roles
(
    id         int auto_increment
        primary key,
    name       varchar(200)                        null,
    created_at timestamp default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP not null,
    updated_at timestamp                           null,
    deleted_at timestamp                           null
);

-- auto-generated definition
create table permissions
(
    id         int auto_increment
        primary key,
    name       varchar(200)                        null,
    created_at timestamp default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP not null,
    updated_at timestamp                           null,
    deleted_at timestamp                           null
);

-- auto-generated definition
create table permission_role
(
    role_id       int                                 not null,
    permission_id int                                 not null,
    created_at    timestamp default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP not null,
    updated_at    timestamp                           null,
    deleted_at    timestamp                           null,
    constraint fk2
        foreign key (role_id) references roles (id)
            on update cascade on delete cascade,
    constraint fk3
        foreign key (permission_id) references permissions (id)
            on update cascade on delete cascade
);

create index permission_role_index
    on permission_role (role_id);

create index role_permission_index
    on permission_role (permission_id);
```

So, I have `RolesModel` and `PermissionsModel` as below:

```
class BaseModel extends Model
{
    protected $table;
    protected $primaryKey;


    use SoftDeletes;

}




<?php


namespace App\Model;


use Carbon\Carbon;

class RolesModel extends BaseModel
{

    protected $table = 'roles';
    protected $primaryKey = 'id';

    protected static function boot()
    {
        parent::boot(); // TODO: Change the autogenerated stub

        static::deleting(function ($roles){
            $roles->permissions()->detach();
            $roles->groups()->detach();
        });

    }

    public function permissions()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(
            PermissionsModel::class,
            'permission_role',
            'role_id',
            'permission_id');
    }

    public function groups()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(GroupsModel::class, 'group_role');
    }
}



<?php


namespace App\Model;


class PermissionsModel extends BaseModel
{
    protected $table = "permissions";
    protected $primaryKey = "id";

    public function roles()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(RolesModel::class, 'permission_role');
    }

}
```

Now, when I delete a role, Although the record of the`roles` is deleted by using Soft delete, all the rows inside the `permission_role` will be deleted hardly. How can I apply soft delete to the `permission_role` table?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Soft delete on a intermediate table for many-to-many relationship](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17350072/soft-delete-on-a-intermediate-table-for-many-to-many-relationship)

Comment: use detach or attach

Answer (score 0):

You can soft delete any element of the intermediate table by creating a model (not pivot model but a regular one). Then you can retrieve any element and soft delete it.

```
<?php


namespace App\Model;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;


class PermissionRole extends Model
{
    use SoftDeletes;

    protected $table = 'permission_role';

...

}
```

Or you could try in your RoleModel to do use the `updateExistingPivot` method and set the 'deleted_at' instead of using `delete()`

```
$roles->permissions()->updateExistingPivot($permissionId, [
    'deleted_at' => now(),
]);
```

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#updating-a-record-on-the-intermediate-table

Comment: Doesn't the `BaseModel` already have a `use SoftDeletes`? Or is this not inherited?